# problems when installing kaazing websocket gateway

Tags: kaazing

I use windows 7, apache 2.2.22 at port 80 and geoserver 2.1.3 at port 8080. 
I download and run kaazing 3.5 msi x64 installer to install it locally on my laptop. I followed the official guidelines from the site. The msi succesfully installed the gateway. 
But gets installed in C:\Applications Files\etc. not in C:\Program Filesx68\etc.
Anyhow, I tried to start the services, I ran the demo-services.start.bat and a notification came from windows saying that the Windows Fire Wall has blocked some of the features of java. So I hit "Allow" and wait. Command line says something like

```
 "Sending data to  ucd://localhost/50505, ucd://localhost/50506"
```

for over an hour, nothing happens. So I thought something went wrong with windows and java. I uninstall the kaazing, edit the Windows Fire Wall settings to allow java and re-install kaazing. The notification is not showing up now, but when I ran the demo-services.start.bat, still does nothing, just says the same thing. When I visit

```
 http://localhost/8000
```

gives an 404 error.
I tried everything, chanching ports, uninstall and re-install a couple of times, installing while not connected to the internet, checking the windows fire wall settings, manually running demo-services.start.bat and gateway.start.bat . The gateway.start.bat actually runs ok and says that the gateway started, but still an 404 error when I visit localhost/8000. Installation through msi is always completed with no errors. But the Gateway does not work. Is it the fire wall, the demos bat file, I dont get it...

Tips/hints?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is get the Gateway running successfully first. So don't worry about running demo-services.start.bat yet.

From the Windows Services application, start Kaazing WebSocket Gateway. Then go to C:\Program Files\Kaazing, locate your installation and look in the log directory. Open error.log using a text editor and verify there are no errors.

If there are no errors, you should be able to open `http://localhost:8001` from a browser. (Note, you had `http://localhost/8000` in your example, but that last slash should be a colon.) You can use either port 8000 or 8001, but 8001 is where the samples are.

If you are using a firewall or something else that is intercepting ports, then you'll need to make sure ports 8000 and 8001 are accessible.

If you're not sure, start a different server process on port 8000 or 8001 (e.g. configure Apache to listen on port 8000 or 8001) and see if the browser can connect.

> The msi succesfully installed the gateway. But gets installed in
>   C:\Applications Files\etc. not in C:\Program Filesx68\etc.

The Gateway is not an executable itself, but runs in a JVM. Therefore there is no 32bit code which constrains the application to be installed into C:\Program Files (x86). Thus C:\Program Files made the most sense.

You could use a 32-bit JVM which would reside in C:\Program Files (x86), but the Kaazing files are abstracted from that via Java, so C:\Program Files is a reasonable location for the Gateway.

BTW There is a forum on the Kaazing website for Kaazing questions.

Comment: Thanks for the anser. Yes that was the problem, the x64 or x32 version of the msi installer. I uninstalled the x64 version and install the x32 and works just fine. It resided in C:\Program Files (x86). I really hate that, when it happens, creating a problem out of my own negligence. About the Kaazing forum, they say that they updating it and I could not login. Oh, BTW, by "C:\Applications Files\" I just ment C:\Program Files. It was a mistranslation from greek to english. I'm greek, using greek Windows and some filenames are in greek, so, my mistake.